# Header transition

Tags: css, css-transitions

here is my website and I have problems with transition in header.

When I scroll down, header menu (both background and menu items) have transition but when I scroll up only background have transition.

https://jsfiddle.net/CRooY3/dxpx8m9z/

```
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.8s;
  -moz-transition: height 0.8s;
  -ms-transition: height 0.8s;
  -o-transition: height 0.8s;
  transition: height 0.8s;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're transitioning `line-height` on `header.smaller .nav-menu` so it's only transitioning on the `.smaller` class, not the default class. To have the `line-height` transition when you add or remove `.smaller` to `header`, just apply the `transition` to `.nav-menu`

https://jsfiddle.net/dxpx8m9z/1/